# Synchronizing two or more image_transport subscriptions

Tags: cv-bridge, message-filters, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I wish to be able to take two subscriptions from two image_transports and synchronize them using boost::bind and message_filters::Synchronizer. But message_filters::Synchronizer only uses sensor_msgs::Image and message_filters::Subscriber.

How do I synchronize image_transport and not message_filters::Subscriber ? so that I can finally use the input with cv_bridge to get a cv::Mat .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12235/synchronizing-two-or-more-image_transport-subscriptions/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a duplicate of [Synchronizer and image_transport::Subscriber](http://answers.ros.org/question/673/synchronizer-and-image_transportsubscriber). If not, please elaborate.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2